# Form builder and pages

Tags: xforms, orbeon

How can i split a form  created in Form Builder in several pages and link these pages between them?

Do i need to use a page flow ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find an answer to your question this how-to: [Create a wizard or multi-page form with Form Builder](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/form-builder-wizard).

Comment: Thanks, but i can see anymore the bar buttons . Also, it would be nice to have a generic solution with a previous button.

Comment: Right: when you put a <fr:buttons> in the page, Form Runner doesn't include the regular buttons. Which buttons would you like to have in addition to the Next/Previous? And yes, it would be nice if this was more of a Form Builder built-in feature, but at this point you need to do a bit of XForms programming to implement those buttons.

Comment: Well, all regular buttons + next/previous buttons. But first i really need "pdf", "save", "previous" and "next" buttons.

Comment: Good point. I added a note about this in the section "Including standard buttons" of: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/form-builder-wizard.

Comment: Great, it works. For the pdf button i need to set visibility property to true otherwise i get only the current section in the pdf generated.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the update, and I am glad this indeed works for you.